# Setting Letter Spacing in RDLC Reports

Tags: rdlc, letter-spacing

Is there a way to set the Letter Spacing on textboxes of RDL/RDLC reports.
It should work when exporting to pdf.

Comment: Choosing the right font is your answer, I think.

Comment: The space needed between letters I need is not in the Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MS-RDL documentation, changing letter spacing isn't supported.

The Style tag only has the properties Style.FontFamily, Style.FontSize, Style.FontStyle, Style.FontWeight and Style.TextDecoration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-rdl/ea446209-9c6a-46ce-b472-fae8b8350b37

---

A workaround is to create your own font with a custom letter spacing set inside  the font itself, but that has many drawbacks... You have to modify the font yourself, if you need two different spacing you also need two different fonts, doesn't look great on variable width fonts without a lot of work, etc.

But if you just need one type of font spacing with one monospace font, it's not too bad:
[Example of a font with custom letter spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC65S.png).

I used the technique described in the third text on this thread of the Dafont forums:
https://www.dafont.com/forum/read/243182/is-it-possible-to-set-letter-spacing-to-the-whole-font-project-at-once

> Hey I figure it out! Here are the instructions if someone needs them. Space between glyphs in evenly scaled and glyphs do not overlap.
> First open the font in Font Forge.
>
> - Element / Font Info / Change the name (otherwise you override original font)
> - Edit / Select / Glyphs worth outputting
> - Metrics / Set Width / Scale by %
> - File / Generate Fonts / True Type .ttf / Generate